# How to create diacritical characters with the Dvorak keyboard on Mac?

Tags: dvorak

I configured the Dvorak keyboard and its almost working. I need to write chars like 'á' typing two keys, but when I type the first the ' char already shows. How to fix this?

Comment: There may be languages with a single diacritical (and no other diacriticals) repeated over vowels, such as in Spanish: á, é, í, ó, ú. 

Would it be possible to set a single key without the `Option` key, such as "\`" to behave as "´" (left to #1 key), which doesn\`t require double- or triple-pressing keys (`Option+whatever+whatever`)?

Or even set `Option-Vowel` to output each vowel with an accent (á, é, í, ó, ú; and uppercases)? 

The best chance would be to have both above options always available to test both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diacriticals for vowels and some consonants are created using the "dead key" system.

First you type the "dead key" by holding down two keys at the same time; for example, Option-E, which produces "´". Then immediately after that you let go of the two keys and then type the vowel that you want the accent to appear above. So in this example, to get "é", you type Option-E, let go, then type "e".

If you want "á", then you first type Option-E, then let go and type "a".

If you want "í", you first type Option-E, then let go and type "i".

Here are the dead keys in the Dvorak layout, highlighted in orange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The dead keys seem to be different for programmer's dvorak. Does anybody know where I can find the dead key layout for for programmer's dvorak?

Comment: @izhang05 `CMD+SPACE`: "keyboard" > Keyboard > Input Sources > Click on "Show Input menu in menu bar".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OS 10.7 and higher, try just holding down the key for the base letter.  You should get a popup menu of accented versions (the Character Picker) from which you can choose the one you want.

Comment: That method is useful on occasion, but it is *much* too slow if you are typing entirely in a language that uses a lot of diacriticals. Learning to use the "dead keys" is much faster.